# Pandas number of unique users grouped by year-week

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a report_date column that I want to aggregate by its year-week and count the number of unique users.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

datastring = StringIO("""\
report_date  user_id
2015-12-01         1
2015-12-01         2
2015-12-01         2
2015-12-02         2
2015-12-02         3
2016-01-01         1
""")

df = pd.read_table(datastring, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df['report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['report_date'])
```

Output I want:

```
2015-48    3
2016-00    1
```

I have come up with a solution (posted below) but it's relatively slow when using a much larger dataset (> 1MM rows). Curious if there's a better solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you try `df.groupby([df['report_date'].dt.year, df['report_date'].dt.week])['user_id'].nunique()`

Comment: They seem to be the same speed with this dataset. I'll try it in my larger one.

Comment: Yes 20x faster with my larger dataset  [300ms vs. 6s] . Please post your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your column is already datetime there is no need to convert to string and groupby on the string, we can group on the [year and week](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) component and then just call [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas.Series.nunique):

```
In [108]:
df.groupby([df['report_date'].dt.year, df['report_date'].dt.week])['user_id'].nunique()

Out[108]:
report_date  report_date
2015         49             3
2016         53             1
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: How is that possible? can you post data and code to show this

Comment: I edited the dataset in the question by modifying the last row. Your code for me prints:
`2016         53             1`. It's as if `dt.week` uses "retail" weeks.

Comment: I think this is to do with the date falling into the 53rd week `2016-01-01` as it overflows, the date `2016-01-04` returns `1` as the week value.

Comment: Perhaps the 2nd element in groupby should be: `df['report_date'].dt.week.mod(53)`?

Comment: I don't know what you should really do in this case as it's technically correct in some sense

Answer (score 1):

```
(df.assign(report_week=lambda x: x.report_date.dt.strftime('%Y-%W'))
  .groupby('report_week')
  .user_id
  .nunique()
)
```

### Edit

I ended up modifying @EdChum's suggestion to get rid of the cases like '2016-53' when report_date is `2016-01-01` by grouping by the week number modulo 53:

```
df.groupby([df.report_date.dt.year, df.report_date.dt.week.mod(53)]).user_id.nunique()
```